# Is it possible to have a payout from a smart contract to a bank account?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, smart-contract-wallets

A company wants to use smart contracts to their applications. The problem is that many customers in the market aren't familiar with having a crypto wallet. So is there a possibility to have the payout executed through a smart contract to the customer's bank account? If not, is there any alternative way to utilise the benefits of smart contracts while still be able to have the payout to your client's bank account?

Comment: You might want to talk to an on/off-ramp company like [Transak](https://transak.com/) or [Ramp](https://ramp.network/). This is not possible by default with smart contracts.

Comment: Loopring has fiat on-ramp support. But the fees aren't low, which is a problem for small transactions.